# Add content externally into wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering if this is possible in wordpress, I would like a user to edit text for a post/page on another site, or instance of the main wordpress site and then update the text which would then change on the main site. I want the user to see just plain text and no wordpress admin editing areas.

Comment: Yes this is possible, but depends on a few factors, but simply can be done with an external form and a PHP page to link to the WP database. - what code have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: I've not tried any code as I didn't know where to star or if it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

External Page: Create an HTML form and send the data to Your WordPress page.

Pseudo-Code (do not forget to add security!):

In WordPress functions.php:

```
add_action('init','check_external_submission');

function check_external_submission() {
  if(isset($_POST["ext"]) && $_POST["ext"] != "") {

    wp_insert_post(array("post_content" => $_POST["content"], "post_title" => $_POST["title"]);

  die;

  }
}
```

Check wp_insert_post function here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post